# Invariant differential operators on equivariant vector bundles over Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, lie-groups, vector-bundles

This is a quick and dirty formulation of my question, with the hope that experts will quickly figure out what I am looking for and provide a reference.

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and let $\pi:E\to G$ be a finite dimensional real or complex $G$-equivariant vector bundle, i.e., $\pi(gs)=g\pi(s)$ for all $s\in E$. Then $E$ is trivial since the simply transitive action of $G$ defines $G$-invariant sections $e_j\in C^\infty(E)$ that comprise a global frame. The same happens with the tangent bundle $TG$ and the endomorphism bundle $\mathrm{Hom}(E)$. The vector space of (left) $G$-inavriant vector fields in $C^\infty(TG)$ is a Lie algebra isomorphic to the Lie algebra $\mathrm{Lie}(G)$, whereas the vector space of $G$-invariant endomorphism fields in $C^\infty(\mathrm{Hom})$ is an associative algebra isomorphic to $\mathrm{gl}(\dim E/G)$. Let $\nabla$ be the flat connection on $E$ corresponding to $G$-translation.

**Question:** Let $\operatorname{D}:C^\infty(E)\to C^\infty(E)$ be a $G$-invariant partial differential operator. I believe that it can be written as
$$
\operatorname{D}=\sum_{k=0}^m D_k(\nabla^k),
$$ 
where $D_k\in\mathrm{Lie}(G)^{\otimes k}\otimes\mathrm{gl}(\dim E/G)$. I think I know how to prove this, but does anyone know of a reference where this is stated? Thank you.

Comment: My first thought would be [the book of KMS](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf), perhaps somewhere in the last chapter?

Comment: Thanks for the book. I had a very quick look, and it was hard to find it there. If I define my category of bundles to consist of the single object $\mathcal{T}$ with morphisms being $G$-transformations, then probably I can make $\operatorname{D}$ a natural operator, so that the book's machinery applies. But then the conclusions seem rather unrelated. Will need to think more though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if there's a theorem in there you can cite and forget, just seemed worth mentioning. I think the proposition in 51.15 seems at least of the right form?

Comment: Well, right, it resembles the desired thing in its appearance. And it may be the general statement when $\operatorname{D}$ is not PDO but a more general equivariant map. What we need is probably a much more precise version of it when the operator is a PDO as above.